# Get and use the previous state from local storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I am building 3 diffent modes/radio buttons with ant design react and I will like to get the previous state from the local-storage and assign it to my value.

It works only when I hard code the value, there must be a cleaner way to achieve this.

```
  class Settings extends React.Component {
    state = {
      mode: 'Something Mode 1',
    }


  componentDidMount() {
      chrome.storage.local.get('AllModes', (result) => {
        this.setState({ mode: result.AllModes})
      })
    }



      handleMode () {
          let currentMode = localStorage.getItem(['AllModes']);
        console.log(currentMode)
        this.setState(( currentMode ) => {
          return {
              mode: currentMode.mode
          }
      })
    }

  <RadioGroup onChange={this.onChange}
              className="radio__group"
              defaultValue={this.handleMode}>
  </RadioGroup>
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this, but I'll describe a simple one.
You can persist the component's state in `localStorage` as a JSON-encoded string and restore it when the component is recreated.

We can define our save and loading methods:

```
function getStoredComponentState(initialState) {
    const storedState = localStorage.getItem(checkedStorageKey);
    return storedState ? JSON.parse(storedState) : initialState;
}

function storeComponentState(state) {
    localStorage.setItem(checkedStorageKey, JSON.stringify(state))
}
```

We initialize our state from what was stored, providing a default in case there is no stored previous state:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = getStoredComponentState({
      checked: false,
    })
  }
```

We persist any changes made to storage when they happen:

```
setState(state) {
    super.setState(state);
    storeComponentState(state);    
  }
```

And it works! You can make a change, refresh the page, and see that the previous state is restored.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8otyxhb3/4/)